# Outlook 2010 does not use the local pst file to send/receive mail

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

My company use Exchange Server with Outlook. Before, it works well with the Outlook 2007. But recently, I've been forced to move to Outlook 2010. Although I've configured all in the `Control Panel/ Mail/ Data Files` to use my local .PST file as default, the Outlook 2010 does not work as I want. It still store every mail on the 100MB .OST file that represent my folder on the mail server. Then every day I must move the mail from the .ost to the .pst manually.
Please help me to check what wrong with my Outlook 2010 ?
Many thanks!

Comment: Have you [turned off Cached Exchange Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/turn-on-or-off-cached-exchange-mode-HP010355560.aspx) ?

Comment: @harrymc sure I don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To set the default delivery location for an Exchange account to a PST file in Outlook 2007 or 2010, you must start with changing your default storage location to PST file, just as in Outlook 2003:

```
Outlook 2010
File-> Account Settings-> Account Settings…-> tab Data Files
```

Accept the warning about changing the default Outlook Data File and restart Outlook. (You probably did this step already.)

You are not done yet!

Once you’ve restarted Outlook, go back to your account settings but this time select the E-mail tab. Here, select your Exchange account and press the "Change Folder" button at the bottom. Accept the warning and **select the root folder of the PST file as the new storage location**.

Restart Outlook again to complete the process.

http://www.msoutlook.info/question/591

Answer (score 1):

Outlook 2010 in an Exchange environment stores messages and settings on the server, the local cache is the .OST file.

#### Outlook OST File:

> The .ost file is synchronized with the items on the server that runs
>   Exchange. Because your data remains on the Exchange server, you can
>   re-create this .ost file on your new computer without having to back
>   up the .ost file.
>
> Windows 7 and Windows Vista
>   drive:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook
>
> Windows XP     drive:\Documents and Settings\user\Local
>   Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook

So, your email is working as designed currently.

It sounds like what you want is to setup an auto-archive for 2010. This will move your Exchange data to an offline .pst file.

[How to edit Auto-Archive:](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/automatically-move-or-delete-older-items-with-autoarchive-HA010354967.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010362337)

1. Click the File tab.
2. Click Options.
3. Click Advanced.
4. Under AutoArchive, click AutoArchive Settings.
5. Select the Run AutoArchive every n days check box, and then specify how often to run AutoArchive.
6. Select any other options that you want. You can choose to have old items deleted automatically at AutoArchive.

Just remember the limitations of the .pst format. Files should not exceed 2GB, and make sure you have a backup if your email is important.